# Can closure of an orbit under a reductive action contain infinitely many orbits?

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups

To be more specific, let $G\subseteq GL(V)$ be a **reductive** linear algebraic group over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. For $v\in V$, can the (Zariski) closure of $Gv$ in $V$ contain infinitely many $G$-orbits? If no, why? If yes, what would be a "simplest" example?

In case this matters, still more specifically I am interested in the case of *nilpotent* orbits, i. e. when that closure contains the zero vector.

**Later**

The question has been reposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/q/420637/41291 and Jason Starr produced two kinds of examples in comments. Let me cite the simplest one here:

> ... consider the postcomposition action of $\mathbf{GL}_2$
> on the vector space $W=\operatorname{Mat}_{2\times 2}$ of $2\times 2$ matrices. There is an open orbit,
> namely $\mathbf{GL}_2$. However, for the induced action on the locus of rank 1
> matrices, the kernel of the rank 1 matrix gives an invariant of the
> action that is an element in the projective line. Using this example,
> you can induce examples for all noncommutative reductive groups
> (obviously this cannot happen for multiplicative group schemes).